# Web logic: string index out of range: -16 in initializing my context

Tags: java, client-server, weblogic, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

> I dont know my error if its is at my weblogic server or in my code.
>   could anyone explain my error log.

```
public class Type4Conn{

        public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception{
            String username="SYSTEM";
            String password="system";
    //      java.sql.Driver myDriver = (java.sql.Driver)
    //              Class.forName("weblogic.jdbc.rmi.Driver").newInstance();
    //              String url =  "jdbc:weblogic:rmi";
    //              java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
    //              props.put("weblogic.server.url", "t3://hostname:port");
    //              props.put("weblogic.jdbc.datasource", "myDataSource");
    //              java.sql.Connection conn = myDriver.connect(url, props);



            //Class.forName("weblogic.jndi.rmi.Driver").newInstance();
            Properties p=new Properties();

            p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");

            p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://http://192.168.1.188:7001");

            p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);

            p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

            InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext(p);

            DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("ds_orclmrcos"); // "java:ds_orclmrcos"    java:comp/env/persistence/

            Connection con=ds.getConnection();

            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("insert into TBL_CUSTOMER(CUST_ID, CUST_FNAME, CUST_MNAME, CUST_LNAME,CUST_ADDRESS,CUST_STATUS)"+
            "VALUES('C-002', 'ALVIN', 'C.','TEST','MANILA', 'PERMANENT')");
           // int a=st.executeUpdate("insert into TBL_ values('test','testuser',2)");

            System.out.println(" records inserted");
```

> Here is my code. I couldn't understand my error. i'm new in web logic..
>
> Here is my error log

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -16
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.NameParser.parseURL(NameParser.java:447)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.parseURL(ORBHelper.java:678)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReference(ORBHelper.java:528)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.InitialContextFactoryImpl.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactoryImpl.java:85)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.InitialContextFactoryImpl.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactoryImpl.java:31)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:46)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.rest.client.Type4Conn.main(Type4Conn.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It your code - remove the double protocol fragment in "Context.PROVIDER_URL". I think it should be

```
"t3://192.168.1.188:7001"
```

Comment: it works.. thanks. and i'm having another problem again.. Unhandled exception in lookup [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]